# How to calculate the probability of winning three sets in a tennis match

Tags: probability

A tennis player A has a probability of $\frac{2}{3}$ of winning a set against a player B. A match is won by the player who first wins three sets. Find the probability that A wins the match.

Am not getting too far with my reasoning so far:

P(A wins in three sets) = $(\frac{2}{3})^{3}$

P(A wins in four sets) = $(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times{3 \choose 1}\times\frac{1}{3}$

P(A wins in five sets) = $(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times{4 \choose 2}\times(\frac{1}{3})^{2}$

P(A wins in six sets) = $(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times{5 \choose 3}\times(\frac{1}{3})^{3}$

P(A wins in seven sets) = $(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times{6 \choose 4}\times(\frac{1}{3})^{4}$

and so on.

So P(A wins) =

$(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\,\,\textbf{+}\,\,(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times3\times\frac{1}{3}\,\,\textbf{+}\,\,(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times6\times(\frac{1}{3})^{2}\,\,\textbf{+}\,\,(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times10\times(\frac{1}{3})^{3}\,\,\textbf{+}\,\,(\frac{2}{3})^{3}\times15\times(\frac{1}{3})^{4}\,\,\textbf{+}\,\,\cdots$

and so on.

I can't see how to get this series in to a form where I can see the sum to infinity. Was hoping to see a geometric progression or some such thing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The match can only involve 3, 4 or 5 sets (if A has not won after 5 sets then B has won at some stage)

Comment: To your original question:  For problems like this, it is easiest to imagine that all $5$ sets are played, regardless of whether or not a winner is determined before the fifth.  It's easy to see that this doesn't change the ultimate winner.  Now all you need to do is to compute the probability that $A$ wins at least $3$ sets out of $5$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is so easy! I was too focused on A to notice that if A hadn't won in after five then the contest would end because B would have won. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The alternative approach, which you took is to compute the probability for each of the mutually exclusive cases of A winning in exactly $3,4,$ or $5$ sets.   Your posting already did all of the legwork for that approach, and that approach also produces the right answer.